# Splitting exterior derivatives on product manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

Let $M_1 \times M_2$ be the product of two smooth manifolds $M_1, M_2$, and let
$\mu$ be a $k$-form on the product. Set $n_1 := \dim M_1$ and $n_2 := \dim M_2$.

The question is whether the product manifold structure induces a canonical splitting of the exterior derivative in the sense that
$$ \operatorname{d}\negthinspace \mu = \operatorname{d}_1 \negthinspace \mu + 
\operatorname{d}_2 \negthinspace \mu \, .$$

Indeed, if one looks at the coordinate expression
$$\mu = \frac{1}{k!} \, \mu_{i_1 \dots i_k} \, \operatorname{d}\negthinspace x^{i_1}\wedge 
\dots \wedge \operatorname{d}\negthinspace x^{i_k} \, ,$$
in product coordinates
$$\left(x^1, \dots, x^{n_1},x^{n_1+1}, \dots, x^{n_1 +n_2} \right) 
= \left(x^1_1, \dots, x^{n_1}_1,x^{1}_2, \dots, x^{n_2}_2 \right) \, , $$
then
\begin{align}
\operatorname{d}\negthinspace \mu 
&= \frac{1}{k!}  \, \left( \sum_{j_1=1}^{n_1}  \frac{\partial \mu_{i_1 \dots i_k}}{\partial x^{j_1}_1} \, 
\operatorname{d} \negthinspace x_1^{j_1}
 + \sum_{j_2=1}^{n_2} \frac{\partial \mu_{i_1 \dots i_k}}{\partial x^{j_2}_2} \, 
\operatorname{d} \negthinspace x_2^{j_2}  
\right)\wedge \operatorname{d}\negthinspace x^{i_1}\wedge 
\dots \wedge \operatorname{d}\negthinspace x^{i_k} 
\\
&=  \frac{1}{k!}  \, \left( \sum_{j_1=1}^{n_1}  \frac{\partial \mu_{i_1 \dots i_k}}{\partial x^{j_1}_1} \, 
\operatorname{d} \negthinspace x_1^{j_1} 
\right) \wedge \operatorname{d}\negthinspace x^{i_1}\wedge 
\dots \wedge \operatorname{d}\negthinspace x^{i_k}   
 +  \frac{1}{k!}  \, 
\left( \sum_{j_2=1}^{n_2} \frac{\partial \mu_{i_1 \dots i_k}}{\partial x^{j_2}_2} \, 
\operatorname{d} \negthinspace x_2^{j_2}  
\right)\wedge \operatorname{d}\negthinspace x^{i_1}\wedge 
\dots \wedge \operatorname{d}\negthinspace x^{i_k}  \, .
\end{align}
(Of course, one needs to anti-symmetrize to get the components of the $(k+1)$-forms.)

Is there a way to define this invariantly e.g. by using projections onto some subbundles of
the tangent bundle/tensor bundles of the product? A quick search in the literature did not really yield anything. One would expect this to be more common, if this were a thing.

EDIT: To maybe give some motivation/context for why one would want to do this, consider the projection mappings onto the respective factor
$$\operatorname{pr}_i \colon M_1 \times M_2 \to M_i \colon (m_1,m_2) \mapsto m_i \, ,$$
a differential form $\alpha$ on say $M_1$, as well as a vector field $X$ on the product $M_1 \times M_2$. One shows easily that formally
$$X \lrcorner \left( \operatorname{pr}_1^* \alpha \right) = \operatorname{pr}_1^* \Bigl( \bigl((\operatorname{pr}_1)_* X \bigr) \lrcorner \alpha \Bigr)  \, .$$
($\lrcorner$ is contraction, the upper and lower stars denote pullback and pushforward, respectively)

However, the expression in parentheses on the right hand side is not a differential form on $M_1$, so
$$\operatorname{d} \left( \negthinspace \operatorname{pr}_1^* \Bigl( \bigl((\operatorname{pr}_1)_* X \bigr) \lrcorner \alpha \Bigr) \right)
\neq 
\operatorname{pr}_1^* \left( \operatorname{d}   \Bigl( \bigl((\operatorname{pr}_1)_* X \bigr) \lrcorner \alpha \Bigr) \right)$$
It is the splitting I was asking for that would allow this equality to hold, if $\operatorname{d}$ were replaced by $\operatorname{d} \negthinspace _1$ on the left hand side.

Comment: Using the projections $\pi_i$ onto the $i$th subbundle of the tangent bundle does not seem to work, as one would get "cross terms":
$$ \operatorname{d}_i \negthinspace \mu \left(Y_1, \dots, Y_k \right) := 
\operatorname{d} \negthinspace \mu \left( \pi_i(Y_1), \dots, \pi_i( Y_k) \right) $$

Comment: Consider $\mu = x dy$ on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sorry, I really do not see what you are trying to say. Of course, $\operatorname{d} \negthinspace \mu = \operatorname{d} \negthinspace x \wedge \operatorname{d} y$, but that would just mean $\operatorname{d}_1 \negthinspace \mu = \operatorname{d}_\negthinspace \mu$ and $\operatorname{d}_2 \negthinspace \mu = 0$

Comment: Surely you want $d_1$ and $d_2$ to satisfy some properties other than $d = d_1 + d_2$. Otherwise you could set $d_1 = d$ and $d_2 = 0$ as in your previous comment. Could you elaborate on what more you require of $d_1$ and $d_2$? Whatever your hoping for, I'm pretty sure a form such as the one I gave will illustrate the non-existence of the desired splitting.

Comment: Please see above, I actually gave a coordinate-expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\pi_1,\pi_2$ denote the canonical projections and $A_1=\pi_1^*TM_1$, $A_2=\pi_2^*TM_2$. We have the canonical decomposition of vector bundles which splits $T(M_1\times M_2)$ into "horizontal" and "vertical" parts.
$$
T(M_1\times M_2)\cong A_1\oplus A_2
$$
This in turn gives rise to a decomposition of exterior powers
$$
\Lambda^kT^*(M_1\times M_2)\cong\bigoplus_{p+q=k}\Lambda^pA_1^*\otimes\Lambda^qA_2^*
$$
which gives us projections $P^{p,q}$ to each factor of this direct sum. We can use these to write the decomposition as
$$
d_1=\sum_{p+q=k}P^{p+1,q}\circ d\circ P^{p,q},\ \ \ \ \ d_2=\sum_{p+q=k}P^{p,q+1}\circ d\circ P^{p,q}
$$
That said, this decomposition may not do what you want it to. The equality you give:
$$
X\lrcorner\pi_1^*\alpha=\pi_1^*(\pi_{1*}X\lrcorner\alpha)
$$
Doesn't make sense, since the pushforward $\pi_{1*}X$ isn't generally well defined. In fact, $X\lrcorner\pi_1^*\alpha$ cannot generally be expressed as a pullback. One can write a similar expression using [Cartan's magic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product#Properties), but an extra Lie derivative appears:
$$
d(X\lrcorner\pi_1^*\alpha)=\mathcal{L}_X(\pi_1^*\alpha)-X\lrcorner\pi_1^*(d\alpha)
$$

Comment: I need to sit down again during the week and check if everything works before I accept your answer and award the bounty. Two points after a quick glance: 
1) I am pretty sure that in the second line on the right hand side you need an exterior product instead of a tensor product to get anti-symmetry. Nothing that would invalidate your argument though. 
2) Read the line I gave as: 
$$\pi_1^*\vert_m \left( \left( (\pi_1)_*\vert_m \, X_m \right) \lrcorner \alpha_{m_1} \right)$$
with $m=(m_1,m_2)$ --which makes sense. Your are right however, that it is not the pullback of a $k$-form on $M_1$.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to take the wedge product of different vector spaces (since there is no notion of antisymmetry). The total space is instead isomorphic to the tensor product using the identification $\mu\otimes\nu\mapsto\mu\wedge\nu$. To your second point, you're correct that the equality makes sense pointwise, but we cannot define $\pi_{1*}X\lrcorner\alpha$ as a global object, much less define an operator $d_1$ which acts on it.

Comment: 1) You do need the exterior product, as you can easily see by comparing a choice of bases for the right and left-hand sides. Your argument that one cannot do this, as one is dealing with different spaces is void, as each $A_i^*$ may be viewed as a subbundle of $T^*(M_1 \times M_2)$ --- something that is easier to see if you define the $A_i$s using the projection endomorphism fields for the tangent bundle. That is, you antisymmetrize using tangent vectors on $M_1 \times M_2$.

Comment: 2) As you have agreed that the expression $\beta_m$ above makes sense pointwise, observe now that the mapping $m \mapsto \beta_m$ is a smooth section of $\bigwedge^{k-1} T^*(M_1, M_2)$ and thus a $(k-1)$-form on $M_1 \times M_2$. I do understand your concern with the exterior derivative in the original post now though: What I meant is that on the right hand side the exterior derivative should treat $m_2$ as a fixed parameter (which is implicit, as it is the exterior derivative on $M_1$).

Comment: 3) I have found time to take a better look at the construction you gave: Using the projections $P^{p,q}$ is a great idea! Not sure whether it helps me going forward, but as an answer to the question, it seems to work.

Comment: To 1), While it's fine to think of the image of $P^{p,q}$ as a kind of "internal" exterior product in this case, the space is isomorphic to (and more conventionally thought of as) a tensor product. To 2), you can make this interpretation work by looking at the projection $\Pi_1:T(M_1\times M_2)\to A_1$ rather than $\pi_1:M_1\times M_2\to M_1$. One can then define a derivative $d_1$ on the exterior powers of $A^*$ and write $d(X\lrcorner\Pi_1^*\alpha)=\Pi_1^*d_1(\Pi_1X\lrcorner\alpha)$.